# How can I find overloaded operators in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Given that there are plenty of overloaded operators in Kotlin standard library how can I find them and their corresponding actions for each stdlib's class that declares them?

Example: recently I have discovered that `+=` adds an element to `MutableCollection`.

I could have done it by going to `MutableCollections.kt` and finding there a declaration `...operator...plusAssign(t: T)` but ofc I had no idea that it exists and can be found exactly in that file.

Maybe there is any official reference to see them in one place?

Comment: There's no one place to find all of them. I suggest when working with these classes to occasionally browse what's available in the auto-complete when you type a dot after an instance. Over time, you'll learn them. Some can be tricky, because it's not always easy to remember if something applies just to Lists, or all Iterables, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

In [Operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) documentation page, you will find [Augmented assignments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html).

[image]

You can use either `List<T> += T` or `List<T>.plusAssign(T)`.

If you want to quickly lookup mini-doc (and you are using IntelliJ/Android Studio) you can Hold ***CTRL + Q***, it would show a mini dialog containing enough info.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloads can be defined anywhere(including outside the standard library), so it is not practical to make a list of all operator overloads.

You can find a list of all overloads in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html).

To summarize the documentation the following can be overloaded:

- `+a`     `a.unaryPlus()`
- `-a`     `a.unaryMinus()`
- `!a`     `a.not()`
- `a++`    `a.inc()`
- `a--`    `a.dec()`
- `a + b`  `a.plus(b)`
- `a - b`  `a.minus(b)`
- `a * b`  `a.times(b)`
- `a / b`  `a.div(b)`
- `a % b`  `a.rem(b), a.mod(b) (deprecated)`
- `a..b`   `a.rangeTo(b)`
- `a[i]`   `a.get(i)`
- `a[i, j]`    `a.get(i, j)`
- `a[i_1, ..., i_n]`   `a.get(i_1, ..., i_n)`
- `a[i] = b`   `a.set(i, b)`
- `a[i, j] = b`    `a.set(i, j, b)`
- `a[i_1, ..., i_n] = b`   `a.set(i_1, ..., i_n, b)`
- `a()`    `a.invoke()`
- `a(i)`   `a.invoke(i)`
- `a(i, j)`    `a.invoke(i, j)`
- `a(i_1, ..., i_n)`   `a.invoke(i_1, ..., i_n)`
- `a += b`     `a.plusAssign(b)`
- `a -= b`     `a.minusAssign(b)`
- `a *= b`     `a.timesAssign(b)`
- `a /= b`     `a.divAssign(b)`
- `a %= b`     `a.remAssign(b), a.modAssign(b) (deprecated)`
- `a == b`     `a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null)`
- `a != b`     `!(a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null))`
- `a > b`  `a.compareTo(b) > 0`
- `a < b`  `a.compareTo(b) < 0`
- `a >= b`     `a.compareTo(b) >= 0`
- `a <= b`     `a.compareTo(b) <= 0`

Comment: It is a good list to look into. But the problem is how one can exactly find that `+a` i.e. `a.unaryPlus()` is assigned to `collection.add()` specifically for collections or to some other action in other case? Ofc except for digging into stdlib's source code.

As u mentioned 
> Operator overloads can be defined anywhere(including outside the standard library)
so that's why I asked only about stdlib scenarios

Comment: Can't you just use ctrl+B/go to definition within intellij on the operator?

Comment: Sure I can, but then I need to write `list += el` first, but I don't know yet that this operator is overloaded as `list.add(el)`, so basically I don't use it. So it is in some way chicken - egg problem

Comment: Also, some of these are defined as extension functions, so you won't easily find them just by looking at the source for the relevant class.